# Apache Tika: Parsed PDF contains rectangle box , how to remove/parse these chars?

Tags: pdf, apache-tika

I am parsing pdfs with apache tika, but I have these in the result String .
I think it's a enumeration dash. How can I remove this from the result string or parse it the right way?
Other characters are working fine e.g. $ % & and so on.

Here is the code to parse from an InputStream:

```
 private SolrInputDocument getDocument(InputStream stream, String docPath) throws SolrServerException {

    SolrInputDocument solrDocument = new SolrInputDocument();

    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(); // Should auto-detect!
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
    pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(false);
    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();

    parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
    parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.add("encoding", "unicode");
    try {
      parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
      String body = handler.toString();
      body = CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL.removeFrom(body);
      solrDocument.addField("id", docPath);
      solrDocument.addField("body", body);
      solrDocument.addField("url", docPath);
      solrDocument.addField("extension", PDF_EXTENSION);
    } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
      throw new SolrServerException(e);
    }
    return solrDocument;
  }
```

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika?

Comment: I added the code in the question.

Comment: Did you try following https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-PDFTextProblems ?

Comment: In other words, probably your PDF is missing the information required for consistent, expected text extraction results.